# Cannot filter files using Kendo Upload with rRazor

Tags: javascript, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I saw no information on this topic really, except for info on how to filter files when using the latest Kendo library. So I am posting how I did it for others to use if they need to.

Answer (score 0):

This is Kendo being used in Razor Syntax:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                      .Name("procfiles")
                      .Async(a => a
                          .Save("SavePF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                                  .Remove("RemovePF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                          .AutoUpload(true)

                      ).Files(f =>
                      {
                          if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ProcedureFile))
                          {
                              f.Add().Name(Path.GetFileName(Model.ProcedureFile));
                          }
                      })
                      .Multiple(false)
                      .ShowFileList(true)
                      .Events(e =>
                      {
                          e.Error("accountEventEditController.uploadProcFileError");
                          e.Select("accountEventEditController.onProcFileUploadSelect");
                          e.Upload("accountEventEditController.onProcFileUpload");
                          e.Success("accountEventEditController.onProcFileSuccess");
                          e.Remove("accountEventEditController.onProcFileRemove");
                          e.Complete("accountEventEditController.onProcFileComplete");
                      })
                    )
```

As you can see, you can hook into the "Select" event. Then I have a .js controller handler file, that executes the following code to filter file types.

```
var onChkFileUploadSelect = function (e, type) {

    var files = e.files;
    var acceptedFiles = [".pdf", ".xlsx"];
    var isAcceptedImageFormat = ($.inArray(files[0].extension, acceptedFiles)) != -1;
    console.log(files[0].extension);       

     if (!isAcceptedImageFormat) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $(targetErrorControl).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps some out there.